# How to use laravel-jsvalidation under laravel-modules?

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 6/nwidart/laravel-modules 7 app I installed proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation
in the directory of my module but I got errors that

```
Class 'JsValidator' not found
```

When I used proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation for all app and in blade file I had :

```
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/jsvalidation/js/jsvalidation.js')}}"></script>
{!! JsValidator::formRequest('\Modules\Pages\Http\Requests\PageTypeRequest', '#form_page_type_edit'); !!}
```

But after I removed proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation in root app and installed under my module

I found the file  at path Project/Modules/Pages/vendor/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/public/js/jsvalidation.js

and tried :

```
<script src="{{ asset('Modules/Pages/vendor/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation/public/js/jsvalidation.js')}}"></script>
```

But still the same error.
I tried

```
composer dump-autoload
```

both in app root and in package dir and failed.
Which way is correct ?

Thanks!

Comment: did u publish assets .? `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Proengsoft\JsValidation\JsValidationServiceProvider"`

Comment: I tried to run it under  my module page and got error : Could not open input file: artisan
. Have I to run it under app root ?

Comment: I run the command in the root, but it did not help, I still get the same error